# GeoServer style multiple label inside shield

Tags: geoserver, style

I want to add multiple labels inside a circle shield.

I also want to set different locations for all labels inside the circle shield.

[image]

I made this for one label.

How can I do this for multiple labels?

If multiple labels are not possible, how can I change the label location inside the shield?

```
* {
    stroke: black,lightgray;
    stroke-width: 3,2;
    label: [name];

    font-family: 'Ariel';
    font-size: 5m;
    font-fill: black;
    shield: symbol(circle);
}
:shield {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
    size: 10m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate something that looks a little like what you want using:

```
* {
    stroke: black,lightgray;
    stroke-width: 3,2;
    label: '  ' [STATE_FIPS] '
'[STATE_FIPS] '-' [STATE_ABBR]'
   ' 34;


    font-size: 10px;
    font-fill: black;
    shield: symbol(circle);
    shield-resize: proportional;
    shield-margin: 4;

:shield {

    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
    size: 10px;

}
}
```

Note the `'` around the newlne characters inside the label, and the use of `shield-resize` and `shield-margin` to adjust the size of the circles.

[image]